# Customizing admin index: is it possible to retrieve the original name of the model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm trying to customize the admin index of an open source app without changing too many things.

I thought I could easily do what I need just by checking the name of the models contained in app_list.models.
Something like:

```
if model is "interface" or "device":
    show it
```

But i can't find a value that doesn't change depending on the settings and language of the django instance.

if i print some info in the template with:

```
{{ app_list.1.models.2 }}
```

I get:

```
{'perms':
  {'add': True, 'change': True, 'delete': True},
  'add_url': '/nodeshot-server/admin/nodeshot/interface/add/',
  'admin_url': '/nodeshot-server/admin/nodeshot/interface/',
  'name': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f67fced6ed0>
 }
```

The add_url and admin_url depend on the settings, infact on my local instance "nodeshot-server" is the folder of the project while online is just "/admin/nodeshot/ecc.".
The name key is also unreliable because it depends on the language in use, so if the language is Italian the name key won't be "interface" but "interfaccia".

Is there a way to retrieve the original name of the model (instead of the translated one) without changing the view? I don't really know what "django.utils.functional._*proxy*" although it looks like a mecchanism for lazy evaluation.

If is not possible I suppose I will have to write a custom view for the admin index.. right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to hide some models? You're only telling us that your solution fails but not what you want to do.

Comment: i want to move some models on a different table. I want to change the layout basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is:

Use the bit that doesn't change in the if clause:

```
{% if '/nodeshot/interface/' in model.admin_url %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options here. First, yes, you could simply override `AdminSite.index` and pass whatever you like to the context. If you go with that approach, you'll have to create and use an `AdminSite` subclass, and register your apps manually (`admin.autodiscover()` will no longer work).

The second option is to try to make use of the info you are provided. `admin_url` may change in part depending on context, but the last piece `/nodeshot/interface` will always be the same for that app and model. You can use a regex to search for this piece and respond accordingly. Though, since you're in the template at that point, you'd have to create a custom templatetag or filter to do the work. A filter would probably be your best bet. You can pass the model dict to it and return a boolean, which you can then use inside `if` statements.

**nodeshot/templatetags/nodeshot_filters.py**

```
import re

@register.filter
def goes_in_different_table(model_dict):
    if re.search(r'/nodeshot/interface/', model_dict['admin_url']):
        return True

    return False
```

**templates/admin/app_index.html**

```
{% load nodeshot_filters %}

{% if model|goes_in_different_table %}
    <!-- do something -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I suspected i had to do that but I hoped I was wrong.. sounds like a lot of work to do something quite simple!

Comment: wait a moment! you are right the last part of the url does not change therefore I can use the admin_url parameter but I do not need a template tag!
I can just do
{% if '/nodeshot/interface/' in model.admin_url %}

How come i didn't think about it. Thank you for suggesting to use part of the URL!

Answer (score 0):

You can [override the admin template](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ExtendingAdminTemplates) for each model. And don't duplicate the whole template file, override just the template block you want to change.